# I have a json object with css string and i wanna remove the backslash from style attribute (only) not all the backslashes like (\n , \t ...)

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor

i wanna remove a json string like

```
"<p><span style=\"font-size:72px\">zxczxcxczxczxczxczxc</span></p>\n"
```

and i need to retrive the text with its style but it doesn't work because of the backslashes inside the style attribute

i tried to solve it with regex but it removes all backslashes but i need them in some cases

```
this.rule = this.ProgramSubmitService.rule.replace(/\\"/g, '');
```

i need the output like this

```
<p><span style="font-size:72px">zxczxcxczxczxczxczxc</span></p>\n
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define "some cases".
For your example you can use the quotes to decide if you want to keep the backslash or not.

This removes every backslash with a postfixed quote.

```js
let str = '<p><span style=\\"font-size:72px\\">zxczxcxczxczxczxczxc</span></p>\\n'
console.log ( str.replace (/\\"/g, '"') )
```